# Publish outside unit test results in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, tfs

I got an xml file with test results.
I tried to add the results to Visual Studio 2008.
I did almost everything right except getting the project name which i can't extract from the .xml file to the .trx file
The question is what is the correct format of the .trx file so it will show me the project name.

Answer (score 1):

.trx files don't actually contain any information on the project that they are for.

As a reference, if you are converting NUnit tests to .trx so you can import them you might want to look at http://codeplex.com/nunit4teambuild which already provides this functionality.

Otherwise you might find it useful to look at [Dominic Hopton's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/dhopton/archive/2008/06/12/helpful-internals-of-trx-and-vsmdi-files.aspx) explaining some of the internals of trx files